# Variable populated in Page_Init but null in DropDownList SelectedIndexChanged event handler

Tags: asp.net, webforms

Every page request, even postback, I populate a variable in the Page_Init event, but it is null when needed in the DropDownList SelectedIndexChanged event (in the same request).

My code behind (user control) looks like this...

```
public partial class CourseInfoDetail : System.Web.UI.UserControl
{
  protected List<CRS_vwCourse2> _offerings;
  protected bool _test;
  protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
     _test = true;
     using (CRSDataContext dc = new CRSDataContext(Config.ConnString))
     {
        List<CRS_vwCourse2> _offerings = (my query here).ToList();

        //code removed here, but _offering is not used for anything other than displaying data here
```

My event handler code is simple...

```
protected void ddlLocationId_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  //_test is true here
  //_offerings is null here
```

If I move the code to the Page_Load event it works okay and _offerings has the right values in the DropDown handler, but my other code doesn't work as some controls need to be repopulated in Page_Init so they are there when the postback data is populated by ASP.NET.

Note that I populate the List variable every postback as I don't want to persist it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove `List<CRS_vwCourse2>` from

```
List<CRS_vwCourse2> _offerings = (my query here).ToList();
```

You are declaring local variable `_offerings` inside `Page_Init` and the class member `_offerings` stays unassigned.

Comment: Thank you so much. I knew I was doing something stupid but couldn't see it. I'm surprised there is no error displayed when doing something like this.

Comment: @Igor's answer sure did help, but I couldn't accept for the first 10 minutes... Accepted now.